# Exchange rule to trigger on "From" addesses of format "email <email>"

Tags: exchange, spam, spam-filter

We are receiving large email flow with an interesting pattern of "From" address. They forge body "From" address as "spoofed local email ". Example: `From: user@domain.com <forged@foreigndomain.com>`. I have tried capturing such emails with a regex pattern of `*@*@*` but Exchange errors on creating a rule with this pattern. How should I create a rule to trigger on such "From" header?

Comment: You should really get yourself a mail gateway to do your filtering so you don't have to mess with regex and exchange doesn't have to waste its resources on spam.

Comment: @Jon EOP is present and still lets stuff in.

Comment: If you have EOP couldn't you contact their support about this? Unfortunately all spam filters will let something in. I have never worked at a place were we used regex in exchange so I can't be much help.